# GKTurnBasedMatch Network Issues

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I've been trying to implement a way to notice when my app gets disconnected from Game Center since ending a turn while disconnected breaks the app. I just started testing on my iPad with the WiFi off and noticed that even when I completely quit the app, it automatically authenticates my player and signs me into game center. It even loads game data from recent games. I then tried going on the game center app itself and the only thing that caused a network error was clicking on the "Games" tab. Obviously much of the data is being cached so I don't know what to check to see if I'm disconnected.

So **how can I test if the device is connected to Game Center?** Neither Match data, participants, nor any of their properties are nil, and the player is always authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manage this with two things :

- **Network connection** : with something like [FXReachability](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXReachability) and then `[FXReachability isReachable]`
- **Game Center authentification** :

In your app test authentification with :

```
GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer.isAuthenticated
```

More generally, always test **completion handlers errors** and array existence like this :

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    // what kind of error ?
}
if (matches) {
    // do what you need to do
}}];
```

Hope this will help you a little bit...